# IntelliJ is not enforcing right margin

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, checkstyle

I have a checkstyle active that complains if a line is longer than 100 columns, and I've set my intelliJ config to hard wrap at 100 columns.

The issue is that it is not always enforcing this, resulting in cases where the checkstyle fails and the only way around it is disabling the formatting in the IDE and manually do the formatting.

So this is a short (and stupid) example of where it fails

```
class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String superString = "s";
        String bestString = "b";
        Arrays.asList(superString.split(""))
              .stream()
              .map(superiorString -> Arrays.asList(bestString.split(""))
                                           .stream()
                                           .map(otherSub -> Arrays.asList(superiorString.split(""))
                                                                  .stream()
                                                                  .map(qwerty -> Arrays.asList(
                                                                          otherSub.split(""))
                                                                                       .stream()
                                                                                       .map(dvorak -> null))));
    }
}
```

and here is my intelliJ config:

```
<code_scheme name="stream-manager" version="173">
  <option name="LINE_SEPARATOR" value="&#xA;" />
  <option name="CLASS_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="999" />
  <option name="NAMES_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="999" />
  <option name="PACKAGES_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND">
    <value />
  </option>
  <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="100" />
  <option name="WRAP_WHEN_TYPING_REACHES_RIGHT_MARGIN" value="true" />
  <JavaCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="CLASS_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="9999" />
    <option name="NAMES_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="9999" />
  </JavaCodeStyleSettings>
  <codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">
    <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="100" />
    <option name="KEEP_LINE_BREAKS" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_DECLARATIONS" value="1" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_CODE" value="1" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_BETWEEN_PACKAGE_DECLARATION_AND_HEADER" value="1" />
    <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_BEFORE_RBRACE" value="0" />
    <option name="BLANK_LINES_AFTER_CLASS_HEADER" value="1" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_CHAINED_METHODS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS_IN_CALLS" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_TERNARY_OPERATION" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_THROWS_LIST" value="true" />
    <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_EXTENDS_LIST" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_LBRACE" value="true" />
    <option name="SPACE_BEFORE_ANNOTATION_ARRAY_INITIALIZER_LBRACE" value="true" />
    <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="RESOURCE_LIST_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="EXTENDS_LIST_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="THROWS_LIST_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="EXTENDS_KEYWORD_WRAP" value="1" />
    <option name="METHOD_CALL_CHAIN_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="TERNARY_OPERATION_WRAP" value="5" />
    <option name="IF_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="DOWHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="WHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="FOR_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    <option name="WRAP_LONG_LINES" value="true" />
    <option name="SOFT_MARGINS" value="80,120" />
  </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

Am I just missing some setting, or is this simply a flaw in the formatter?
And is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2):

From `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java` select the `Wrapping and Braces` tab and scroll to  `Chained method calls` then:

- Set `Wrap always`
- Tick the `Wrap first call` option
- Tick the `Align when multiline` option

[image]

With that configuration your code will be formatted like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String superString = "s";
    String bestString = "b";
    Arrays
            .asList(superString.split(""))
            .stream()
            .map(superiorString -> Arrays
                    .asList(bestString.split(""))
                    .stream()
                    .map(otherSub -> Arrays
                            .asList(superiorString.split(""))
                            .stream()
                            .map(qwerty -> Arrays
                                    .asList(
                                            otherSub.split(""))
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(dvorak -> null))));
}
```

That's 68 chars at its widest point.

Comment: Yeah, but I would prefer it aligned. And if intelliJ is unable to do this, then I would consider it a bug

Comment: @munHunger I have updated the answer to address both requirements: alignment and enforcing wrapping.